# ggplot custom theme : some graphic issues with framing

Tags: r, ggplot2, themes

I am trying to create a custom ggplot theme as follow :

```
library(data.table)
library(tidyverse)


# On definit les couleurs
CouleurTitre = "#006CE5" #Bleu titre
Couleur_QuadrillagePrimaire ="#B9CDE5"
Couleur01 = rgb(000,112,192, maxColorValue = 255) # Bleu
Couleur02 = rgb(255,102,000, maxColorValue = 255) # Orange
Couleur03 = rgb(000,176,080, maxColorValue = 255) # Vert
Couleur04 = rgb(255,204,000, maxColorValue = 255) # Jaune d'or
Couleur05 = rgb(192,000,000, maxColorValue = 255) # Rouge
Couleur06 = rgb(128,128,128, maxColorValue = 255) # Gris
Couleur07 = rgb(000,176,240, maxColorValue = 255) # Bleu ciel
Couleur08 = rgb(102,255,051, maxColorValue = 255) # Vert pomme
Couleur09 = rgb(102,255,051, maxColorValue = 255) # Violet
Couleur10 = rgb(247,150,070, maxColorValue = 255) # Saumon

Palette_Test = sapply((sprintf("Couleur%02d", 1:10)),function(x) get(x),USE.NAMES = FALSE)


# Theme 
Attempted_Theme <- theme_classic()+ 
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size=18, face="bold", hjust=0.5, color=CouleurTitre))+
  theme(panel.grid.major = element_line(colour=Couleur_QuadrillagePrimaire, size=0.5, lineend = "butt"))+ 
  theme(axis.title.x = element_blank(),axis.title.y = element_blank())+
  theme(panel.background = element_rect(colour = "Black",size=1.5)) +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank(),legend.position="bottom")+
  theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())

ggtest <- function(...){
  ggplot(...) +
    Attempted_Theme + 
    scale_colour_manual(values =Palette_Test)
}
```

The data used is the following :

```
MWE <- as.data.table(ggplot2::economics) %>%
  melt(.,id="date")
```

Now if I plot something

```
ggtest(data=MWE[variable %in% c("pce","unemploy"),],
       aes(x=date,y=value))+
  geom_line(size=1)
```

[image]

I have two issues with the frame I have created :

- The frame seems to be thicker on the right side and the bottom side, although I would want all to be the same size
- It seems that my grid is on top of my frame, as you can see the gray lines on top of the black lines of the frame. I would like it to be the opposite way

How can I do that ?

Comment: Hi Anthony. Not sure about the first issue. If I save to png the lines look more like having the same size. Concerning the second issue. Try with `panel.border = element_rect(colour = "black", size=1.5, fill = NA)` instead of `panel.background`.

Comment: @stefan Thank you, this works